# How do I search for nodes without incoming edges/relations in AgensGraph?

Tags: cypher, agens-graph

I've tried a bunch of cypher queries, most coming from [this question](/questions/10952332/return-node-if-relationship-is-not-present), but none worked.

E.g.:

```
postgres=# match (a)<-[r]-() where r is null return *;
 a | r
---+---
(0 rows)
```

The last one I tried is this:

```
match (n) where not (n)<-[]-() return *
```

obtaining a syntax error:

```
postgres=# match (n) where not (n)<-[]-() return *;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: match (n) where not (n)<-[]-() return *;
```

I finally fired up Neo4j and found that the above mentioned cypher query works there.

What's the equivalent in AgensGraph (2.1.3) Cypher?

### NOTE

While waiting for the correct solution, I worked around the issue with the following sequence of queries:

1. mark all nodes having an outgoing relation as *children* `match (a)<-[]-(b) SET b.child=true;`
2. find all *non-childen* nodes `match(a) where a.child is null return a;`
3. remove the *child* marking `match(a) where a.child is not null remove a.child;`

Eventually wrapped within a transaction so not to alter the graph properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're query `match (n) where not (n)<-[]-() return *;` is close however you need to add 2 more elements to get the  query to work.

1. Your pattern (n)<-[]-() needs to be surrounded by parenthesis.
2. You need to prefix your pattern with EXISTS

So I ran this query: `MATCH (a) WHERE NOT EXISTS ((a)<-[]-()) RETURN *;` and it worked.

Comment: Thank you. Though this comes after I almost decided to move to Neo4j (and meanwhile I had [another query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67007556/3127111) to write that was already hard for me in Neo4j, I didn't try to write it for AgensGraph). Moreover, is this syntax documented in the docs? I can't find anything about `EXISTS` (that probably led me - at that time - to think it was not supported).